# Remove 1st few characters from a text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that contains the data similar below:

```
2020-05-04T00:00:16.120X "2020-05-04 08:00:02:562" "apple"
2020-05-04T01:00:16.140X "2020-05-04 09:00:02:488" "banana"
2020-05-04T02:00:48.160X "2020-05-04 10:00:02:509" "cherry"
2020-05-04T03:00:54.182X "2020-05-04 11:00:02:518" "papaya"
```

I want to remove the first column that contains the dateX:

```
"2020-05-04 08:00:02:562" "apple"
"2020-05-04 09:00:02:488" "banana"
"2020-05-04 10:00:02:509" "cherry"
"2020-05-04 11:00:02:518" "papaya"
```

hoping for you assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -replace '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}X\s' |
    Set-Content file.txt
```

`-replace` uses regex matching. If you provide no replacement string, then the matching strings will just be replaced with empty string. `^` is start of the string. `\d` is a digit. `{number}` is a quantifier to repeat the previous regex match `number` times. `-` is literal `-`. `\.` is a literal `.`, but it must be backslash escaped because `.` has special meaning in regex. `T` is literal but case-insensitive (you can use `-creplace` for case-sensitive matching). `X` is literal. `:` is literal match. `\s` matches a white space character.

Answer (score 1):

You could just treat it as if it is a CSV and do it his way:

```
Import-Csv ./datafile_in.txt -Delimiter ' ' -Header a, b, c | Select b, c | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ' ' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File ./datafile_out.txt
```